# Can you do a stat reset on your citizens?

Tags: citizens-of-earth

I just finished chapter 1 and found a pretty good groove using the Baker, Mascot, and Brother and I'm leveling up fairly well.  However, I notice that the level up stat bonuses that I get from Baker and Mascot don't really look like they will do Brother much good since I'm using him primarily as a tank and those other members just give special attack.

Are you able to reset stats at some point in the game or should I just use more citizens that have better stat up synergies with Brother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to directly affect stats of your citizens, but you are able to "level down" your citizens using the Yoga Instructor which you are able to meet in Chapter 2.  It seems that every time you level up, you receive bonus ranks in certain stats depending on which citizens are accompanying the citizen that leveled.  Whenever you use the Yoga Instructor's talent, you can see how many bonus rank that citizen has.

While viewing the current stats of that citizen, you can remove an over all level from that citizen and apply a bonus rank to one of their stats in order to improve it.  After that, the citizen will be able to regain their level through the normal level up process with the same normal exp requirement that that level originally had with no penalty to exp growth.

The higher the talent level or the yoga instructor, the more bonus ranks you receive for each level you sacrifice.  At the start, you receive 2 bonus ranks, and I believe the maximum is 4.  From what I can tell, 2 bonus ranks usually nets you one stat point.